# Using ORDER BY in $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

If I query the database using this code, I get an array of 4 objects as expected.

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ppm_playlists");
var_dump($rows); die();
```

But if I query using this, I get an empty array.

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ppm_playlists ORDER BY sort-order ASC");
var_dump($rows); die();
```

Is there a "trick" to using "ORDER BY" in the database class that I am missing in the documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting that query in the phpMyAdmin to see if you also get empty result.

Comment: I did. I changed field name to sort_order and everything worked. I guess sort-order is reserved???

Comment: user850010, If you can rephrase your comment and make it an answer, I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `sort-order ASC` to `sort_order ASC`

When having problems like this it helps to put the problematic query in the phpMyAdmin to locate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the query failed is because `sort-order` is interpreted as `sort - order` (subtracting the column named `order` from the column named `sort`). If you wish to keep the hyphen in your column name, you would have to wrap the column in backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM ppm_playlists ORDER BY `sort-order` ASC;
```

[Note](http://www.hockinson.com/programmer-web-designer-denver-co-usa.php?s=46), however, that using hyphens in column names is not recommended.